# HTTP Request for get page with Special:Export

Tags: http-headers, wikipedia

How i can use Special:Export for my purposes. I send next header from my app:

```
string request = "POST en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Export&action=submit HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                 "Host: en.wikipedia.org\r\n"
                 "Content-Length: 32\r\n"
                 "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                 "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"
                 "catname=&pages=ukraine&curonly=1";
```

but it render to me page about error:

> HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request Server: squid/2.7.STABLE9 Date: Mon, 23 Apr
>   2012 14:45:12 GMT Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 3111
>   X-Squid-Error: ERR_INVALID_URL 0 X-Cache: MISS from
>   amssq46.esams.wikimedia.org X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from
>   amssq46.esams.wikimedia.org:80 Connection: close

I need to create tools to replace inwiki links to help in translation. I'm sure what some such tool already exist, but i want to do it myself.

EDITED: I use c++ and sockets.

EDITED: new request:

```
string request = "POST https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Export&action=submit HTTP/1.1\r\n"
//string request = "GET https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Export&pages=ukraine&curonly=1\r\n"
                 "Host: en.wikipedia.org\r\n"
                 "User-Agent: MyCoolTool\r\n"
                 "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n"
                 "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\n"
                 "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"
                 "Content-Length: 32\r\n"
                 "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                 "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"
                 "catname=&pages=Ukraine&curonly=1";
```

When i try to get just page

```
string request = "GET http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukraine\r\n" ...
                 "User-Agent: YolaTool/0.1\r\n" ...
```

i have

> Scripts should use an informative User-Agent string with contact
>   information, or they may be IP-blocked without notice.

Comment: What language are you using? There might already be some library to do that. And why are you writing raw HTTP requests? Doesn't your environment have some better way to make HTTP requests?

Comment: @svick, header is header, language doesnt matter.

Answer (score 1):

There is a reason why I suggested you to use higher-level networking library, that directly supports HTTP: this way, you won't have to deal with the low-level details and you can be sure they are correct.

In your case, the problem is that after the `POST` keyword, there has to be either an absolute URI:

```
POST http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Export&action=submit HTTP/1.1
```

or, more commonly, an absolute path:

```
POST /w/index.php?title=Special:Export&action=submit HTTP/1.1
```

See [RFC 2616, §5.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1.2).

If you fix this, you will get a 403 error, but this time the error message is clear on what to do to fix this:

> Scripts should use an informative User-Agent string with contact information, or they may be IP-blocked without notice.

See [WikiMedia User-Agent policy](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy).

Comment: i have updated question and am i need to register my bot-User-Agent somewhere?

Comment: No, you don't. You can put almost anything there, as long as it doesn't match any of the common blocked user agents (like the default user agent of wget).

Comment: it still not working, but +1)) may be problem in IP, do you know right IP to ask special:export, i use 91.198.174.225

Comment: Whatever DNS search for en.wikipedia.org returns should be okay.